# Casting a constant to a union

Tags: c, types, casting

The following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union {
   int   n;
   char *s;
} val_t;

int main(void) {
  val_t v1,v2;

  v1 = (val_t)"Hello World";
  v2 = (val_t)10;

  printf("%s %d\n", v1.s, v2.n);
  return(1);
}
```

compiles and executes correctly with gcc. If one tries to cast a constant for which there's not a suitable field in the union, an error message is produced.

Looking at the (C99) standard, though, I've not been able to locate the section where this behaviour is described. Hence, my question:

> *Does the C standard guarantee that I can cast a constant to a union type, provided that the union type has a field with a compatible type?*

or, in other words:

> *Is `((val_t)10)` a valid rvalue of type `val_t`?*

It would also be interesting to know if this behaviour is supported by other compilers (or at least MS Visual C++). Does anybody know?

EDIT: 
  Casting to a union is a GCC extension, so it's not a good idea to use it.

Thanks to Maurits and Neil! I didn't think about using -pedantic to check!

Comment: Apart from the fact that this looks like pretty bad programming practice, it is an interesting question. I thought that after 20 years of C programming I've seen it all, Apparently not :)

Comment: @MauritsRijk It's actually a great way to implement generic containers in C.  You make the key of the container a union type with fields such as int, double and void pointer, and the comparitor function you pass in knows what type it needs and accesses the appropriate member of the union.  I actually don't see why it's not a standard part of the language, since the way union's are defined in K&R, each member is aligned to the lowest address, the union is guaranteed to have proper memory alignment for all it's members, and be wide enough to hold the widest one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [GNU C language extensions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html) casting to a union is marked as an extension to the C standard. So most probably you won't find it in the C99 or any other C standard. The IBM C compiler supports this extension as well.

Answer (score 7):

```
[neilb@GONERIL NeilB]$ gcc -Wall -pedantic sw.c
sw.c: In function 'main':
sw.c:11: warning: ISO C forbids casts to union type
sw.c:12: warning: ISO C forbids casts to union type
```